# collectstatic yielding the error No file or directory : '/app/static' despite having that directory present

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am trying to deploy a django app via Heroku. Initially I was getting errors on deployment and set `heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1`. Once collectstatic was disabled the app deployed without errors. Now that I want to add my static files I unset `heroku config:unset DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC` and tried deploying again but received errors saying my push was rejected. Here is what I believe is the relevant portion of the traceback:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:'/tmp/build_7f46d0854acc9adac5d065056bd2bc4f/s

Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
```

My next step was to run `heroku run python manage.py collectstatic` to get a more accurate traceback and then I received the following error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/static'

This step puzzles me because I have exactly that directory in my app:

```
lang_site
-- __psyache__
-- static
---- lang_site
------ pic.jpg
------ style.css
-- __init__.py
-- settings.py
-- urls.py
-- views.py
-- wsgi.py
```

As a shot in the dark I added the literal directory `app/static/` in the same directory as `settings.py` only to yield the same error.

I also added the extra `static_dir` and `static_root` lines in my `settings.py` as seen below:

```py
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Can anyone recommend some next steps?

EDIT:
as recommended, I removed the second call to `os.path.dirname` in my `BASE_DIR` variable and reran collectstatics. This time I received the following message:

```
You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings:

    /app/lang_site/staticfiles

This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?
```

I don't have an *exact* directory with those names. Can anyone help me understand this?

Comment: You have a folder `/app/static` in your file system **root**?

Comment: Is `BASE_DIR` the `lang_site` folder or it's parent folder?

Comment: @KlausD. I'm not sure. How do I find my file system root? I'm using windows if that matters

Comment: @JosephRajchwald I'm pretty sure you don't need the second call to `os.path.dirname` when you are assigning `BASE_DIR` since `BASE_DIR` just needs to be the root of your app (the `lang_site` folder)

Comment: @IainShelvington I removed the second call to `os.path.dirname` and tried rerunning `heroku run python manage.py collectstatic ` but am still receiving the same error.

Comment: @IainShelvington I tried running it again after the edit and got some different results. I updated the main question with the new message from the console.

Answer (score 1):

Create static folder under the root directory that is where all your app resides. Not in the directory where settings.py resides.